# Как получить координаты центра экрана Yandex MapKit

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Как получать координаты центра экрана на андроид в Yandex MapKit ? То есть нужен колбек, который будет слушать изменения/перемещение по карте и отправлять геолокацию объекта по центру экрана

Comment: То что мне нужно было - интерфейс CameraListener в Yandex MapKit

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует смотреть на [CameraPosition](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/map/Map.html#_5) карты для получения координат её центра.